# How to deactivate focus rects on one component in Swing/Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, focus

For my current project, i'm using Swing and the Nimbus look and feel. The look and feel draws focus rects that look great on buttons, text fields and so on. Unfortunately, a focus rect is also drawn on any tab of a TabbedPane.

How can i deactivate drawing the focus rect around those tabs?

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be handled by

```
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabPainter
```

You might be able to replace the `Focused` one(s), but I haven't tried it. Here are the [`TabbedPane` UI defaults](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html), as well as links to some [examples](http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/nimbus-uimanager-uidefaults/).